# Redirect one of two domains on one Wordpress installation

Tags: redirect, multi-language, domain, wp-config

I have to domains: mydomain.dk and mydomain.de. Both are showing the same page in danish. I have a plugin that takes care of the languages, but I need to connect the .de domain to the german 'language layer'.

How can I redirect mydomain.de to mydomain.dk/?lang=de. The mydomain.dk must stay as it is.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which plugin do you use? WPML?

Answer (score 2):

You could check the contents of the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` array when the site is loaded, by placing the conditional checking logic in your header.php file of your site and then redirect the user to the appropriate language from there.

For example in header.php add:

```
$incomingUrl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($incomingUrl == 'mydomain.dk') {
  wp_redirect(URL FOR THIS LANGUAGE);
  exit;
} else {
  wp_redirect(URL FOR THE OTHER LANGUAGE);
  exit;
}
```

The PHP manual page can also give you more information on the $_SERVER global array here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for a simple script like this, but unfortunately I'm new to php and I am getting an error, when I add this code. Am I doing it 100% right? `code` $incomingUrl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($incomingUrl == 'mydomain.de') {
  wp_redirect('mydomain.dk/?lang=de');
} else {
  wp_redirect('mydomain.dk);
}
`code` of course I set 'mydomain' to the real domain. Where exactly do I have to place the code in the header.php. I placed it at the beginning surrounded by php-tags. Hope you can help!

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: It in danish, but it says that the website redirects to itself.

Comment: and therefore never finishes the request...

Comment: You will need to place it at the top of the file, immediately after the opening php tags. It's weird that it is saying that it redirects to itself, as the point of wp_redirect() is that you can go to a different page on the same site. I have changed the else clause to an elseif like this: 

 if($incomingUrl == 'mydomain.de') { 
  wp_redirect('mydomain.dk/?lang=de'); exit; 
 } elseif ($incomingUrl == 'mydomain.dk') { 
  wp_redirect('mydomain.dk); exit;
 }
 
 Can you let me know if it works, and if not, copy and paste the error exactly.

Comment: Now theres no error showing up, but the mydomain.de doesent redirect to mydomain.dk/?lang=de.

Comment: What happens? Where does it redirect to?

Comment: I think it doesen't redirect at all. Its still the same as without the code.

Comment: Are you able to check your php log and see if it has logged any errors?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: The only other thing I can think it could be is that your headers need flushing as information is being sent before the wp_redirect function call. Try adding ob_start(); directly after the opening php tag and ob_end_flush(); directly before the closing php tag.

Comment: It does not change anything. :(

Comment: The last thing I can think of doing is changing $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; to $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; Without seeing the the rest of your code, I am shooting in the dark :(

Comment: Still the same. I can see why it's difficult for you, because you cannot se the code. But thank you so much for your time :)

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more of a help. You could however research these two pages: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php that might help you some more :)